# Exit X using bash script

Tags: bash, x11, raspberry-pi, lightdm

Well, I'm playing with a Raspberry pi 3 and due to hardware limitations I have to exit X to execute some emulators(using framebuffer), for example. I want to create a bash script to exit lightdm window manager and go into a situation like pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fn (but logged, of course) to implement some automatism. I trying this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service lightdm stop
sleep 5s
#Now I don't know how to bring :7 and log on***
/usr/bin/openmsx -carta /home/pi/Roms/msx/game.zip
```

It's a simple task, but I don't know how to do.

Thank you in advance. Sorry about my english.

P.S.: Another question, if someone knows: Opengl driver is functional, but avoids advance mame of work with his framebuffer driver stuff. Is there some workaround?
P.S.2: I don't want an entire game emulation environment full of games and weird things.

Comment: You have more than one distinct question here. It would be better to ask them as two questions, otherwise you wouldn't be able to accept any of the answers that concentrate on one question but not the other.

Comment: Yes, it's a main question and an optional question. The optional question is not meant to be answered, but is also important because can annul the first one or the need to exit X to play an emulator.